# Making a full browser window responsive Image in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am making my first steps coding. I did some courses in Codeacademy and now I decided to continue learning from the experience while I build a Wordpress child theme.

The thing is that I would like to have a responsive background image in my homepage. I know that I can choose a background image in the customize section, but I think that it would be nice if I learn how to do it using custom fields. And like this, I can also choose which pages I would like to have with a background image.

As I understand I have to write this in my page template but it doesn't work:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('custom_field_name'); ?>');">
```

Is there a way to make this in Wordpress using custom fields?:

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://absolute/path/to/img.jpg');">
```

I've been working on this for a week and I can't find a solution, so I just decided to add my field with the traditional way:

```
<div id="imghome"><?php the_field("images"); ?></div>
```

and then use this css:

```
#imghome img {
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Like this I can see my image bigger, But it doesn't fill completely the browser window.

Do you have some suggestion about it?

Comment: use `background-size:cover`

Comment: Thank you Minal but it doesn't work. The thing is that I can't write this in my page template before: <div style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('custom_field_name'); ?>');"> because wordpress doesn't read it. So I can't make a custom background css

Comment: How u set ur img? in background or in img tag?

Comment: I set my image like this <div id="imghome"><?php the_field("images"); ?></div> and then I made the following css   #imghome img {
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to tell to wordpress in my page template that my image is a background image

Comment: First tell me img is coming or not?

Comment: no. Image is not coming. I should write img in the place of div?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117805/discussion-between-minal-chauhan-and-valentin-verdegales).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an `img`, then background properties will not apply to it. Try using this instead, it is the equivalent of background-cover for image elements:

```
-o-object-fit: cover;
object-fit: cover;
```

If this alone doesn't work, try changing your height/width as well. If you add right and bottom, the image will take up all space between the 4 points:

```
#imghome img {
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
-o-object-fit: cover;
object-fit: cover;
}
```